# make primary key id always in sync with row number

Tags: mysql

once I set this column to primary key auto_increment, then it increases the "id" by one each time, even if i deleted the previous rows, so the first row id may start with 4 or 40, but I hope the id could always go along with the row number, how can I manage to do that in mysql?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: it looks therefore makes me feel, more organized!

Comment: There's really no need to burden the database with heavy load only to feel more organized. The job of primary keys is to identify rows not to number them. You can always get a numbering with the help of a query too.

Comment: Making it in "sync" will actually do harm, more than you think and more than comment box allows me to explain. You think it's "organized", but it's really just making a row uniquely identified. It's not there to be pretty, nor in sync. Leave it be, or if you don't want to - be ready for errors you can never dream of fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't and don't want to do what you're asking.  The primary key, especially when it's just a surrogate key like "1", "2", "3", is important mainly in relation to other tables.  That is, table b need to point its foreign keys at the primary keys of table_a.

Now, what if you could do what you're asking for.  You have two rows in your table_a, with PKs 1 and 2 respectively.  You delete row 1 for whatever reason.  If the row that used to be row 2 in table_a changed its PK to 1, *every other table* that had a foreign key to table_a is now broken.  You need it to keep it's primary key no matter what happens.

If you want to look at an ordered view of your data, you can use the `ORDER BY` clause.  You'll still have holes in your PKs for any row you deleted though, and you want it to be like that.